# How can I get a list of all events on a selected day in fullCalendar?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm currently working with FullCalendar in a React application, and I've come across a condition in the code that checks for the presence of the class 'fc-day-has-event' on a day element. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
!info.dayEl.classList.contains('fc-day-has-event')
```

So here it checks wether day has no event.

```
    return (
        <>
            <FullCalendar
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                initialView="dayGridMonth"
                headerToolbar={{
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth',
                }}
                contentHeight="auto"
                selectable={true}
                dateClick={(info) => {
                    if (
                        !info.dayEl.classList.contains('fc-day-has-event')
```

I'm curious how can I get the events belonging to the selected day, if there are events.

Comment: The only thing you can do is https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents and then filter them by date yourself, unfortunately. Or ask the original event source of the events (e.g. if there's an API you can query, or something)